# After Jenkins update jobs are not coming to UI

Tags: jenkins

After upgrading jenkins from 2.263.4 to 2.346.3 I am facing issue that all job configs are not getting loaded / visible to Jenkins UI.

In Jenkins logs there are errors like below for them:

```
Failed Loading item deploy_system_spec_SingleServicecom.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Validation failed

---- Debugging information ----
message             : Validation failed
scriptId            : The script is not allowed to be executed in a build, check its configuration!

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder$ConverterImpl.callback(ScriptlerBuilder.java:318)
Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : Validation failed
class               : org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder
required-type       : org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder
converter-type      : hudson.util.XStream2$AssociatedConverterImpl
path                : /project/properties/hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty/parameterDefinitions/org.biouno.unochoice.ChoiceParameter/script/scriptlerBuilder
line number         : 46
class[1]            : org.biouno.unochoice.model.ScriptlerScript
required-type[1]    : org.biouno.unochoice.model.ScriptlerScript
converter-type[1]   : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
class[2]            : org.biouno.unochoice.ChoiceParameter
required-type[2]    : org.biouno.unochoice.ChoiceParameter
class[3]            : java.util.ArrayList
required-type[3]    : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type[2]   : hudson.util.RobustCollectionConverter
class[4]            : hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty
required-type[4]    : hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty
class[5]            : hudson.util.CopyOnWriteList
required-type[5]    : hudson.util.CopyOnWriteList
class[6]            : hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
required-type[6]    : hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
version             : not available
-------------------------------
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder$ConverterImpl.callback(ScriptlerBuilder.java:323)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder$ConverterImpl.callback(ScriptlerBuilder.java:307)
at hudson.util.XStream2$PassthruConverter.unmarshal(XStream2.java:535)
at hudson.util.XStream2$AssociatedConverterImpl.unmarshal(XStream2.java:501)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshalField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:454)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:350)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:289)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshalField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:454)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:350)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:289)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132)
at hudson.util.RobustCollectionConverter.populateCollection(RobustCollectionConverter.java:87)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:81)
at hudson.util.RobustCollectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustCollectionConverter.java:78)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshalField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:454)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:350)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:289)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117)
at hudson.util.CopyOnWriteList$ConverterImpl.unmarshal(CopyOnWriteList.java:202)
at hudson.util.CopyOnWriteList$ConverterImpl.unmarshal(CopyOnWriteList.java:178)
at hudson.util.XStream2$AssociatedConverterImpl.unmarshal(XStream2.java:501)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshalField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:454)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:350)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:289)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1421)
at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:189)
at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:160)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1399)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1293)
at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:165)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /opt/jenkins/home/jobs/deploy_system_spec_SingleService/config.xml
at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:167)
at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:375)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$13.run(Jenkins.java:3420)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:175)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1158)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But in Manage Jenkins - Script Approval I am not seeing anything pending approval.

Comment: There is a 100% likelihood you encountered a ,[tables-to-divs migration issue](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#upgrading-to-jenkins-lts-2-277-1). This is [well-documented](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/). You should  go 2.263.4, update plugins, then core, then plugins, repeat. Also documented in my other answers. Google or search.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what exactly went wrong since you've made a bug jump between LTS versions. I would recommend to read [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/) at first and make backups at second.

Check the owner of jobs folder in jenkins home folder on the server which is running jenkins.
Good luck with docs)

Answer (score 0):

I did found out the problem, basically all missing jobs were failing like this:

```
cause-message       : Validation failed
class               : org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder
```

i.e. related to scripler plugin. And with new Jenkins / scriptler plugin version they seems to be by default disabled:
[image]

so needed to go for each of the scriptler scripts and select like this there:
[image]